# Проблема при отправке сообщений

Tags: клиент-сервер, active-directory, postfix, dovecot, altlinux

Есть DC настроенный на windows server 2012, развернул почтовый сервер на alt linux (связка postfix/dovecot) с интеграцией пользователей из AD.
добился аутентификации, но появилась следующая проблема. при отправке сообщения c помощью команды mail письмо отправляется, очередь пуста, захожу в почтовый клиент вижу письмо от root. НО, отправить сообщение себе не могу. Вот log:
[лог](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lx5SiQ4fo0rM_rtrciE6wxUAhlH3rMnO/view?usp=sharing)